# Gradle jar task to add contents of jar files in a directory

Tags: java, gradle, jar, build.gradle

I have a directory of jar files that may be empty or have jar files of various names. I want to unzip them and include them in my fat jar. I've seen use of from zipTree('path'), but this seems to only work with a specific jar/zip file name.

Here is my current gradle task.

```
task buildSweetJar(dependsOn: classes, type: Jar) {
    baseName 'MySweetJar'
    from ([sourceSets.main.output, configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } ])
    from zipTree ('tmp_plug/*.jar') -- this doesn't work
    manifest {
        attributes (
                'Main-Class': 'my.app.SysInit',
                'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' ')
        )
    }
    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF','META-INF/*.DSA'
}
```

1. I want to include/unzip an entire directory of jar files without
   knowing their names. Is this possible?
2. I want the contents of the
       jar files to also be on this jar's classpath. How is this possible?

Update:

I was able to learn FileTree to be able to walk each jar in the directory. I'm not sure how to add this to the classpath, however.

```
FileTree pluginFileTree = fileTree(dir: 'tmp_plug/')
from ([sourceSets.main.output, configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } ])
pluginFileTree.each {
    File pluginJarFile ->
        from zipTree (pluginJarFile)
}
```

Comment: A 'fat jar' isnt just a jar that includes all necessary jars to run your code - I assume you're aware of this?

Comment: Actually, no, I wasn't aware. I'm guessing I don't have my terminology right.

Comment: A fat jar is another name for an executable jar, which you could run on its own from the command line. e.g. "java -jar your_jar_file.jar"  Is this what you want to do, or are you trying to achieve something else?

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm trying to do. The task to create the jar already exists and we use it as an executable. However, I need to add additional items to it for a new purpose. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a framework such as springboot to create a runnable jar.  It will remove the need to hand crank a lot of boiler plate gradle code.  There is a spring-boot gradle plugin which does almost everything for you:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html

I'm not sure how you're managing your dependencies, but storing them on your file system is not good practice.  You should be resolving them from a repository, such as Maven Central.  I'm not sure if you're doing this, but the question suggests that you're not.

Comment: The poster should just use the fatJar plugin. Suggesting spring boot for something that is potentially small in scope is excessive.